# Blazor MAUI - Camera and Microphone Android permissions

Tags: android, blazor, android-camera, mediadevices, maui

I am trying to show live stream from camera & microphone in `<video>` html element.

In blazor file (`sample.razor`) I invoke method to request and show video:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("requestMediaAndShow");
        }
    }
```

In javascript file (`sample.js`) I request stream and assign to video html element.

```
// Create request options
let options = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};

// Request user media
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(options)
    .then(gotLocalStream)
    .catch(logError);
```

But when I am requesting i catch an error like "NotAllowedError: Permission denied".

`AndroidManifest.xml` contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

`MainActivity.cs` contains:

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio, Manifest.Permission.ModifyAudioSettings }, 0);
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to request audio and video stream by javascript in BlazorWebView natively on android?
PS. On both on website and natively on Windows platform works great and no extra permissions are required.

Comment: Interesting question! Do you have a little sample of this somewhere in a GitHub repo I could look at?

Comment: Sure. Repo url: https://github.com/patrykplay/BlazorMauiAndroidDevices

Comment: This might be a bug in BlazorWebView: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3694 (source: I'm the developer of BlazorWebView).

Answer (score 4):

### Updated for 28/02/2023

Since the `GetWebChromeClient()` override does not exist anymore, I figured out a way around it, here is the tutorial:

Step 1:
In `Platforms/Android` create a folder called `Handlers`, inside, create a class:

```cs
    internal class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
        {
            // dirty code, fix this yourself
            try
            {
                request.Grant(request.GetResources());
                base.OnPermissionRequest(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MauiBlazorWebViewHandler : BlazorWebViewHandler
    {
        protected override global::Android.Webkit.WebView CreatePlatformView()
        {
            var view = base.CreatePlatformView();

            view.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Step 2:
Inside `MauiProgram.cs`, add the following handler code:

#1 Using statement

```cs
#if ANDROID
using ClientAppHeavy.Platforms.Android.Handlers;
#endif
```

#2 Inside the method

```cs
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                })
                .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
#if ANDROID
                    handlers.AddHandler<BlazorWebView, MauiBlazorWebViewHandler>();
#endif
                });
```

This will grant all permissions whenever requested, but the `try/catch` is there cause it calls `Grant` multiple times for some obscure reason, so I just did a quick and dirty workaround.

Good luck :)

Comment: This seems to work almost for me. It works for my Javascript QR code library. But it does not work when I am using a regular HTML5 input element in order to capture images from the camera and/or filesystem. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784122/blazor-maui-capture-image-input

Answer (score 3):

Although the Android permissions seem to be granted OK, I suspected the website permissions were not. Not sure if the author of this question is the same person, but [an issue was opened on the .NET MAUI repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3694) as well about this.

While we are looking into making this work out of the box, another helpful user has posted this workaround for now.

Implement your own handler like so

```cs
public class MauiWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
{
    public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
    {
        request.Grant(request.GetResources());
    }
}

public class MauiBlazorWebViewHandler : BlazorWebViewHandler
{
    protected override WebChromeClient GetWebChromeClient()
    {
        return new MauiWebChromeClient();
    }
}
```

And register this handler in your `MauiProgram.cs`:

```cs
builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
{
    handlers.AddHandler<IBlazorWebView, MauiBlazorWebViewHandler>();
});
```

This will automatically grant all the requested permissions from the web side of things.

Comment: Unfortunately this workaround does not seem to work properly, I've updated the github issue with my findings.

Comment: Ah maybe I was too quick. I totally looked over your "didn't fix it completely but nice starting point" comment :D

Comment: Turns out I was too quick as well :D, I only looked at the github issue and missed the more detailed changes made in this question. When I add the changes in `MainActivity.cs` everything seems to work great!

Comment: @GeraldVersluis in MAUI RC1 the method `GetWebChromeClient()` is no longer available for override on the Android build target. Would you perhaps know what the new path for this might be? Maybe this has now been incorporated into the MAUI defaults?

Comment: `GetWebChromeClient()` doesn't exist anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Although the camera permission issue has been solved by @YaRmgl's answer, it will cause a side-effect that there is no response when clicking the HTML5 input element. The workaround is to override the `OnShowFileChooser()` function.

Here is the code:

```cs
using Android.Content;
using Android.Webkit;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui;

namespace BarcodeScanner.Platforms.Android.Handlers
{
    public class MauiBlazorWebViewHandler : BlazorWebViewHandler
    {

        protected override global::Android.Webkit.WebView CreatePlatformView()
        {
            var view = base.CreatePlatformView();
            view.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this.Context));
            return view;
        }
    }

    internal class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        private MainActivity _activity;


        public MyWebChromeClient(Context context)
        {
            _activity = context as MainActivity;
        }

        public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                request.Grant(request.GetResources());
                base.OnPermissionRequest(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        public override bool OnShowFileChooser(global::Android.Webkit.WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            base.OnShowFileChooser(webView, filePathCallback, fileChooserParams);
            return _activity.ChooseFile(filePathCallback, fileChooserParams.CreateIntent(), fileChooserParams.Title);
        }


    }
}
```

The `ChooseFile()` method is implemented in the `MainActivity.cs` file:

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Webkit;
using static Android.Webkit.WebChromeClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BarcodeScanner;

[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    private IValueCallback _filePathCallback;
    private int _requestCode = 100;

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (_requestCode == requestCode)
        {
            if (_filePathCallback == null)
                return;

            Java.Lang.Object result = FileChooserParams.ParseResult((int)resultCode, data);
            _filePathCallback.OnReceiveValue(result);
        }
    }

    public bool ChooseFile(IValueCallback filePathCallback, Intent intent, string title)
    {
        _filePathCallback = filePathCallback;

        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, title), _requestCode);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The full source code:
https://github.com/yushulx/DotNet-MAUI-Blazor-Barcode-Scanner

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing some parts of the permission checks. You should read this section about runtime permissions that were introduced in Android 6.0. For example, I cannot see any override of OnRequestPermissionsResult in MainActivity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=macos#runtime-permission-checks-in-android-60