# Blazor MAUI capture image input

Tags: c#, android, browser, blazor, maui

I have an app which uses the camera to scan barcodes, I have managed to get the Android permissions correct for my Blazor MAUI app in order scan barcodes with a Javascript library. This is working great.

However, in my app I also have a HTML5 input field (for a different purpose) like this:

```
  <input id="captureCameraInput" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

For some reason my javascript camera library works to capture images but when clicking this input field nothing happens. Is there some permission on Android I am missing that is needed to use this kind of input? The same input works great in a browser.

The permissions I am requesting are

```
ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);
```